# Set value of textfield with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am creating a Safari extension that autofill the email.
I managed to get this working but on some sites, the textfield appears to be filled in by the value, but when the website tries to get that value, it gets nothing.

For clarification, my code works on e.g. Facebook, Github, Stackoverflow,.. . But it doesn't work on e.g. developer.apple.com, www.back4app.com, Microsoft,.. .

I've tried to see what the autofill of keychain in safari does, and this shows met the the email actually get's filled in in the HTML  tag. This doesn't happen with my code. But the email is always filled in in the textfield that you see on the webpage.

```
function handleMessage(event) {
    var arguments = event.message;    

    var emailStr = arguments["Email"];

    var nameInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < nameInputs.length; i++) {
        var theFieldName = nameInputs[i].name.toLowerCase();
        var theFieldType = nameInputs[i].type.toLowerCase();

        if (theFieldName.indexOf("email") !== -1) {
            if (!(emailStr === undefined)) {
                nameInputs[i].value = emailStr;
                filledInEmail = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (theFieldType.indexOf("email") !== -1) {
            if (!(emailStr === undefined)) {
                nameInputs[i].value = emailStr;
                filledInEmail = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing those sites are listening to the input change event. Try this:

```
function handleMessage(event) {
    var arguments = event.message;    

    var emailStr = arguments["Email"];

    var nameInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < nameInputs.length; i++) {
        var theFieldName = nameInputs[i].name.toLowerCase();
        var theFieldType = nameInputs[i].type.toLowerCase();

        if (theFieldName.indexOf("email") !== -1) {
            if (!(emailStr === undefined)) {
                nameInputs[i].value = emailStr;
                nameInputs[i].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));//trigger change event
                filledInEmail = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (theFieldType.indexOf("email") !== -1) {
            if (!(emailStr === undefined)) {
                nameInputs[i].value = emailStr;
                nameInputs[i].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));//trigger change event
                filledInEmail = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does something in the good way but it's not perfect yet. So now Microsoft works fine but there are some where it still is the same, like Dropbox.